# Why my jupyter notebook script do not run in Atom console?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I download the script from my Jupyter notebook (.py) in which it runs perfectly but when I open the script in Atom console to run I get this: "Process returned 0" ..
I cannot get the answer that Jupyter releases.

My code I get from Jupyter is this one:

```
import numpy as np

S0 = 100
K = 100
T = 1
r = 0.06
N = 3
u = 1.1
d = 1/u
opttype = 'C'

def binomial_tree_slow(K,T,S0,r,N,u,d,opttype = 'C'):
dt = T/N
q = (np.exp(r*dt) - d) / (u-d)
disc = np.exp(-r*dt)

S = np.zeros(N+1)
S[0] = S0*d**N
for j in range(1, N+1):
    S[j] = S[j-1]*u/d

C = np.zeros(N+1)
for j in range(0,N+1):
    C[j] = max(0, S[j]-K)

for i in np.arange(N, 0, -1):
    for j in range(0, i):
        C[j] = disc*(q*C[j+1] + (1-q)*C[j])

return C[0]

binomial_tree_slow(K,T,S0,r,N,u,d,opttype = 'C')
```

Comment: Unlike in jupyter, you actually need to `print()` variables to output values when running through python. Try `print(binomial_tree_slow(K,T,S0,r,N,u,d,opttype = 'C')` and see if you get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I really appreciate it